# Disable news feeds on Google Launcher

Tags: launcher, google-discover

I'm using the Google Launcher on my Huawei P9. Recently it's been updated so there is a Google feed of some sort when I swipe right from the home screen.

I've been through my settings and turned off as much as possible, but I still see weather and news. The weather doesn't bother me, but I consider it my right to choose if I'm being force-fed politically biased news or violent stories.

I could go back to the Huawei launcher, but my plans are to move to a Google phone in the future anyway. Not being able to turn off news would obviously mean I couldn't choose a Google phone for my future phone.

How to turn this off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option wasn't there before, but it works now.

1. Either swipe right from the home screen or press and hold in a blank area.
2. Select '**Settings**'
3. In the '**Search**' category, select '**Your feed**'.
4. Switch the '**Feed**' slider to off.

**EDIT**

I've since updated my phone and this no longer works for me, but it might work on some older versions of Android.

Answer (score 4):

Android 9, Pixel 2

You can disable the Discover feature (the one that shows news items on the left-most screen of the launcher) by:

1. Go to that screen
2. Select three dots on that screen on the top right
3. Choose "Settings"
4. Under "Search", choose "Discover"
5. Turn off "Discover: see stories related to your interests on the home tab of the app"

Note that this turns off *all* info on that page, eg weather.

Comment: The important keyword here is "Discover".
With Android 12, you will have to click on the top right icon and then:
Settings -> General -> Discover

Answer (score 1):

Press on a blank part of home screen until options appear. Choose settings from foot of screen. Look down the list until you see Google Now. Toggle this to off.

Comment: For me, it was called "Show Google App" instead of "Google Now", but this was how it worked for me. (Android 13)

Answer (score 1):

I had to get the Google News app. Then I uninstalled it. Hold down on the app picture and slide it to the top right of your phone. The words uninstall appears. Move picture on top of it.